# Arduino with the use of LCD i2c adapter (Error Receiving Data)

Tags: arduino, wifi, lcd

Good day! 
I'm currently working on a device with Arduino UNO, NFC/RFID Module v3, esp8266 and LCD with i2c adapter. The process is TAP card, read card data then send via wifi.

Here's the scenario, the code is working fine without the LCD library. I have used the LEDs as my indicators whether my data has been sent or not. Then I decided to use LCD as my visual indicator.I put the library of the LCD i2c and its corresponding code in my previous sketch (which is perfectly working). Successfully compiled and uploaded the sketch. Although it appears that the data has been successfully sent, but the data were not received by the web.

I have tried removing the code of the LCD i2c again, then the device is really working. Successfully sent the data and all.

Here's the link LCD library that Im using: https://github.com/fdebrabander/Arduino-LiquidCrystal-I2C-library/tree/master/examples

What are the possible ways to correct this problem? Thank you very much.

Here's some part of my code with LCD:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtuBP.jpg

Everytime I add the code for LCD like this one:

lcd.setCursor(4,0);
lcd.print("RELOADER");

,data has been sent successfully but was not received.

Removed that part again and data was received.

Comment: You may want to ask this question here: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you need to provide the code. otherwise it is hard to help u. Check your lcd routine and TCP/IP(i guess) communication.

Comment: Added the code sir.